# SQL Server : update table tries to drop nonexistent triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2). I am not using SQL Server Management Studio. I am using a simple webpage with a textarea for a query window that I built myself in PHP, so all I am doing are SQL commands -- no GUI stuff. Never had problems with it before, and I don't think the problems I'm having now are because of my PHP. Anyway, I would most appreciate answers in SQL code rather than answers that recommend I right-click the table name in Management Studio, if you get my drift.

Leading up to the problem...

I used to have three triggers on table `dbo.MyOldTableName`:

```
trgOldUpdate1, trgOldUpdate2, and trgOldInsert
```

I renamed the table using the following code:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.MyOldTableName', 'MyNewTableName';
```

I then dropped those three old triggers and created the following three new triggers (which do the same thing but point to the new table and have new names):

```
trgNewUpdate1, trgNewUpdate2, and trgNewInsert
```

I ran this SQL and saw only the new triggers:

```
SELECT 
    referencing_schema_name, 
    referencing_entity_name,
    referencing_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, 
    is_caller_dependent
FROM 
    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.MyOldTableName', 'OBJECT');
```

I ran this SQL and the old triggers are not there:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers;
```

Now all of that above information is simply background. Here is the actual problem. I ran a simple update command (like this SQL):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyNewTableName] SET ColumnName = ColumnName;
```

...and got these error messages:

> Cannot drop the trigger 'dbo.trgOldUpdate2', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Cannot drop the trigger 'dbo.trgOldUpdate1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Cannot drop the trigger 'dbo.trgOldUpdate1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Cannot drop the trigger 'dbo.trgOldUpdate2', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

- First, why is SQL Server trying to drop triggers on a simple update command (And before you ask, no, the trigger code itself never drops anything at all)?
- Second, why is SQL Server looking for triggers that don't exist?
- Third and most important, how do I stop this from happening?

Many thanks in advance for your clear, concise, and self-contained answers! (Hey, a guy can dream, can't he?)

Comment: Clear, concise and self contained question for you - are you running the UPDATE query from inside Query Analyser, yet on a different part of the page you have the DROP TRIGGER statements selected by accident and when you press F5 it's not executing what you hoped it was?

Comment: I'm not using Query Analyzer at all. I have essentially pasted these commands, one by one, into my html textarea query form and executed each one, one-by-one. So I am in no danger of highlighting the wrong piece of code... everything in the html textarea gets run (and there is only one command in there at a time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there was an error in the trigger `DROP/CREATE` script such that the DROP statements of the old triggers were inadvertently included in in one of the update triggers.  Check the new triggers to see if that is the case:

```
EXEC sp_helptext N'trgNewUpdate1';
EXEC sp_helptext N'trgNewUpdate2';
```

Comment: I will investigate this evening. Thanks for the suggestion -- I had not thought of that possibility.